# How to not connect signals every time I instantiate a scene in Godot

Tags: c#, godot

Is there a way to simply make an object listen to a signal without having to access the specific instance of the emitter??
For example if I want to listen to a newly spawned enemy, I need to connect the signal every time I instantiate one, instead of just connecting it once for all instances until I decide to disconnect them...

Comment: i think u have bad implementation. why u should open each connection for each enemy object? u should only have 1 connection for each user. user only get like json object by view camera. let say u set view camera is  150px x 60px. everytime user move, user get object enemy data. even if no enemy. just set it null. if exist. just loop it into user screen.  in user side it just show data. dont make user side to manipulate logic thing. it makes hole into several hack. like speedhack.

Comment: Thanks Theraot, looks like that's the way of doing it!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without seeing your code/node structure, but it sounds like you would benefit from rethinking your approach. Instead of emitting the "spawned" signal from the spawned instance, try putting "spawned" signal on the script that actually managed spawning the enemies.

So instead of this `node | signal` structure:

```
EnemySpawner
    Enemy | SpawnedSignal
    Enemy | SpawnedSignal
    Enemy | SpawnedSignal
    Enemy | SpawnedSignal
```

You get this

```
EnemySpawner | SpawnedSignal
    Enemy
    Enemy
    Enemy
    Enemy
```

And you only need to connect once to the enemy spawner.

Another approach would be to create a "event/signal bus". Basically an AutoLoad script that any other script can connect to to receive or emit signals.

See this page for an overview: https://www.gdquest.com/docs/guidelines/best-practices/godot-gdscript/event-bus/